# Keep an ASP.NET IIS website responsive when time between visits is long

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis

After years of ASP.NET development I'm actually quite surprised that I can't seem to find a satisfying solution for this.

Why does an IIS ASP.NET site always seem to fall asleep (for 2-6 seconds) after a certain time of inactivity (after several hours), during which no HTTP response is sent from server to client. This happens on any type of site, one page or many, db or not, regardless the settings. How can I fix this?

During the wait time, the server is not busy and there are no high peaks or (.NET) memory shortages. My guess is, it has to do with Windows moving the IIS process to the background and its memory to the page file, but I'm not sure. Anybody any idea?

EDIT: one solution is to send some HTTP request once an hour or so, but I hope for something more constructive.
EDIT: what I meant is: after hours of inactivity, it pauses several seconds on any new HTTP request.

Comment: +1, but belongs on serverfault.

Comment: Are you compiling your site?  If not you're missing out on some very big performance improvements.

Comment: @theminesgreg: sites are compiled, debug is not set, optimizations are on for the (any) dlls. @John: Not sure it belongs on serverfault, as this really troubles me as a programmer, but correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Agree we should assume this is a code problem with the ASP.NET application until it becomes obviously otherwise.

Comment: Note: this is not just one site, it is any site that I've seen, either build by me or by someone else. "Professional" shopping sites show this behavior at night when there's noone online, private one-page experiments show this behavior too. I may be missing a compile/publish setting, but then others have missed that too and I'd love to hear of it.

Comment: Why the "close" vote? Can you clarify? If it needs to be moved elsewhere, please leave a comment.

Comment: Perhaps we should indeed move it to serverfault, as I see now that it is not programming related. How do I go about moving the question?

Comment: Tx (see my comment there: love it!). Should stay on SO then ;)

Comment: I've resolved this issue with simply code-behind, you can check here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27339997/how-to-always-your-warm-up-asp-net-websites-webform-mvc?noredirect=1#comment43136405_27339997](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27339997/how-to-always-your-warm-up-asp-net-websites-webform-mvc?noredirect=1#comment43136405_27339997)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default timeout for IIS is 20 minutes. What this means is if your ASP.NET application does not receive any new requests for 20 minutes, it will shut down the worker process. It can take a considerable amount of time to warm up the process from nothing - loading assemblies into memory, precompilation, etc.

(*Edit*: I put together a simple helper class that resolves the standard timeout issue - basically the web application "pokes" itself every so often to keep the process alive. The ideal approach is to change the setting in IIS, but for servers where this is not possible, my class works quite well. - **Code at the bottom**)

While the worker process is still alive, it should not be deprioritized. Certainly not as quickly as you're describing. It is possible you could relying on items that are cached for a very short period of time, and are falling out when they've not been requested for more than a few seconds. Without knowing more about the details of your application, it's impossible to say.

As usual, profiling your application is the only way to yield concrete information. Using a product like [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm) will help you determine where in the code your application is spending the most time, so you can isolate where the "hang" is occurring.

```
public class KeepAlive
{
     private static KeepAlive instance;
     private static object sync = new object();
     private string _applicationUrl;
     private string _cacheKey;

     private KeepAlive(string applicationUrl)
     {
         _applicationUrl = applicationUrl;
         _cacheKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
         instance = this;
     }

     public static bool IsKeepingAlive
     {
         get
         {
             lock (sync)
             {
                 return instance != null;
             }
         }
     }

     public static void Start(string applicationUrl)
     {
         if(IsKeepingAlive)
         {
             return;
         }
         lock (sync)
         {
             instance = new KeepAlive(applicationUrl);
             instance.Insert();
         }
     }

     public static void Stop()
     {
         lock (sync)
         {
             HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove(instance._cacheKey);
             instance = null;
         }
     }

     private void Callback(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
     {
         if (reason == CacheItemRemovedReason.Expired)
         {
             FetchApplicationUr();
             Insert();
         }
     }

     private void Insert()
     {
         HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(_cacheKey,
             this,
             null,
             Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
             new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
             CacheItemPriority.Normal,
             this.Callback);
     }

     private void FetchApplicationUrl()
     {
         try
         {
             HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(this._applicationUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
             using(HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
             {
                 HttpStatusCode status = response.StatusCode;
                 //log status
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             //log exception
         }
     }
}
```

Usage (perhaps in App_Start):

```
KeepAlive.Start("http://www.yoursite.com/");
```

Comment: You point at some interesting thoughts. I always assumed it never got to the `Application_Start`, but what do I know, perhaps it gets there, loads libs etc, and then resumes. Please note that the time is not 20min (session timeout time), it chokes for a little while after approx 3+ hours, but I'm not sure. The time may be variable. It's not just "a site", it's "all sites" on many systems and IIS / Windows versions. All are .NET 3.5 though.

Comment: On *"but what do I know"* >>> meant to say: I should log, or turn Trace on or whatever. I know ANTS but not sure it can help here: the blocking seems to happen before anything is loaded, which would include ANTS.

Comment: Just noticed same comment here http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30548981/slow-site-startup.aspx, which mentions this idle timeout. It doesn't happen locally, only remote on configurations I do not always manage. It shouldn't take long to figure out whether it's all in this setting.

Comment: +2! That's an excellent little class, with a very nice technique! My own approach so far was with a background thread, but if you know the troubles of threads in ASP.NET I rather avoid them. Using cached objects and its timeouts is excellent. Q. should stay on SO now :P

Comment: The page is down, could you please enter the relevant code here?

Comment: Can you please show us your helper class again? It seems to be offline.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using IIS 7 there is an IIS plugin call Application Warm Up from the IIS team that will help keep everything toasty

I've written a [blog post](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/05/06/keep-your-aspnet-websites-warm-and-fast-247) about my experiences using it.

Comment: Interesting plugin. Also, the 20 min timeout can be set on the application pool. I set it to 24 hours on most servers, which helps (PS: your site is unresponsive...)

Comment: Hilarious - i'm assuming the blog was rebuilding haha - how ironic

Answer (score 0):

If you are only compiling your code behind at the moment, then you might also want to look at **pre-compiling your aspx files at complile time** (rather than runtime, which is the default).  I believe that this on the fly compilation is what takes up most of the time when a dormant ASP.NET site is woken up.  You can read more about it [here](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/05/compiling-aspx-templates-using.html).

Update:

The application pool gets killed when the IdleTime-Out value is reached - this defaults to 20mins (you can change this value). Are you sure that UI isn't getting recompiled after the app is restarted in this case? (I'm not sure if it forces a UI recompile or not).

Comment: While your statement is correct, compiling pages only happens once, even if you do not choose precompiling (which I prefer if I have a say in a project). The issue mentioned in the question is caused after any 20 minutes of inactivity and could be considered the "sleep mode" of the application pool. Check your logs if you have a small local website: when the first customers arrive at 4AM, you will see a long wait time for the very first requests.

Comment: What version of IIS are you using? and Do you have Admin access to IIS?