# Keep MSSQL database (application pool) responsive C#

Tags: c#, sql, application-pool

Firstly let me apologise, as I don't really know how to phrase the question.

The issue I'm having is trying to keep my database 'alive' while users come to my site. An example being, if I build my c# asp.net application and publish it, then try and navigate to it, it takes a while to respond (which I get, I understand it, this isn't an issue for me) the problem is if some person hasn't been to the site for a while, it seems to take a while again, like a session timer has passed, I'm not sure if this is something to do with App Pool recycling?

I've tried to run a scheduled task to hit the database (trying to keep it responsive) every 15 minutes, but this doesn't seem to work, it works well every 15 minutes for say 5 hours, and then I receive a message on a random call that the request has taken over 4 seconds to respond and therefore fails.

My question then, how do I keep my connection to the database / the site responsive so that each time a person requests it, the site loads quickly, rather than having to 'start up'

Kind regards as always

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to increase connection pool size in your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what you want:
Keep an ASP.NET IIS website responsive when time between visits is long: [Keep an ASP.NET IIS website responsive when time between visits is long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670344/keep-an-asp-net-iis-website-responsive-when-time-between-visits-is-long)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider [IIS application auto-start?](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series)

> Some web applications need to load large amounts of data, or perform expensive initialization processing, before they are ready to process requests.  Developers using ASP.NET today often do this work using the “Application_Start” event handler within the Global.asax file of an application (which fires the first time a request executes).  They then either devise custom scripts to send fake requests to the application to periodically “wake it up” and execute this code before a customer hits it, or simply cause the unfortunate first customer that accesses the application to wait while this logic finishes before processing the request (which can lead to a long delay for them).
>
> ASP.NET 4 ships with a new feature called “auto-start” that better addresses this scenario, and is available when ASP.NET 4 runs on IIS 7.5